# Excel complex countifs with embedded if's

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, countif

I want to create a dynamic countifs based on some form controls check boxes.
On columns in which there are no blanks, I do not need to do anything special however if a blank can be present in a column, this becomes trickier and I have to use a sum(countifs()) array formula to get around this.

to increase the difficulty even further, I need to add multiple checkboxes to filter or unfilter values.

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(
Data[creation date],">=01/01/2016",                            regular filter
Data[creation date],"<01/01/2017",                             regular filter
Data[technical],"Y",                                           regular filter
Data[Category],IF($U$17,"<>T",{"*","="}),                      count all and blanks                 
Data[Flow],IF($U$14,"Y","*"),
Data[Status],IF($U$15,{"*","="},"<>Cancelled"),        not cancelled OR pending
Data[Status],IF($U$15,{"*","="},"<>Pending"),
))
```

Although this appears like it MAY do what I intend it to do, it has some side effects that cause it to not work. Due to the way array's work when calculating the values, I think the loop mechanism works like this:

```
for i = 0 to 1
    filter Category[i]
    filter Status[i]
next i
```

instead I would need it to operate like:

```
for i = 0 to 1
    filter Category[i]
    for j = 0 to 1
        filter Status[j]
    next j
next I
```

So is this realistically possible?